# 9's complement for floating point number substruction

Tags: math, digital-logic

**Let A=369.569 B=863.153**

By using 9's complement what is the value of **A-B=?**
And what are the rules to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Find the 9's complement of the second number, add the first number to it and then add 1 to the result of the previous part.